# How can I "reset" BackgroundTint of EditText in Android using databinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have an `EditText` that I want to do something like

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@{vm.foo ? R.color.yellow : 0}" // here I want to say if not foo() then reset tint to null
        android:afterTextChanged="@{(edtitable)->vm.afterTextChanged(edtitable)}"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:onTouched="@{vm}" />
```

I tried `edittext.backgroundTintList = null` and it worked great, but I can't seem to find a way to achieve the same in xml. Thanks!

Comment: How about giving the default color in case of foo() return false ex:  `android:backgroundTint="@{vm.foo ? R.color.yellow : R.color.your_default_color}"`

Comment: I don't have a default color...the init state is drawn dynamically in the library.